# Where is the local temporary file stored, when opening a 2 GB file from a (remote) shared folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares, home-networking, sharing

Let's say ComputerA has a shared folder `C:\data\` containing a 2 GB file `audio.wav` .

On ComputerB (connected to ComputerA in LAN), I can easily open `\\ComputerA\data\audio.wav` in an audio editing software, such as SoundForge.

In ~20 seconds, the file is open, transparently, like if it was stored on a local folder from ComputerB!

**Question: where is stored the temporary file on ComputerB which is a copy of ComputerA's `audio.wav`?**

I searched the whole disk (with an indexing software), and didn't file any file on ComputerB of size ~ 2 GB!

NB: this is *not* related *specifically* to SoundForge, the same question would apply for any 2 GB remote file opened in any software.

TL;DR: when opening a big file from a remote computer with Windows Shared Folders, does Windows keep a local copy to be able to open it in any program, as if it was an ordinary local file? If so, where is stored this local file-sharing cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It isn't stored in Computer B at all.

The network filesystem is intelligent enough to allow other systems to open files, seek, and otherwise act on the files as if they were "local" to Computer B.

Programs can look through files remotely, scan them for the data that they need, and access all the data they need on a "per block" basis without needing to copy the entire file first.

So no, unless the program itself is copying the file and putting it somewhere (in which case check the "cache" settings for that program) then there is no local copy of the file on Computer B.